# drupal installed modules are not visible in menu

Tags: drupal, menu, module, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7.24:

So I installed and enabled some extra modules (2 examples: metatags and colorbox).
I can see the colorbox option in my menu under configuration->media, but the metatag option is not in the menu. It should be under configuration->search and metadata, but it's not. I double checked that the module is enabled, but i must be missing something else.

any help is appreciated as i'm only learning drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed both the Chaos Tools and Token modules? Metadata requires both of these modules.

You should not be able to enable a module without the installed dependencies.  When you say "the module is enabled" does it appear on the module list or does it also have a check indicating that it is enabled?

If you haven't installed Chaos Tools and Token, I'd recommend doing that first.  If you have, describe how you installed Metadata--did you do it through the admin interface (by url or upload) or did you use sftp or drush?

I tried an install of metadata and it appeared in the configuration menu appropriately.